# Why IPC::System::Simple(capture) is not working with arguments

Tags: perl

I am trying to call a second script from the main script. When I am passing the argument in the command itself using capture, it's working. But when I am trying to send the command and arguments separately in capture function it's giving me an error that it can't find the specified file.

**Second script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $word= $ARGV[0];

my $crpyt = "$word crypted";
print "$crpyt\n";

my $decrypt = "$word decrypted";
print "$decrypt\n";
```

**main.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture capturex);

my $cmd= 'perl xyz.pl Hello';
my @arr = capture($cmd);

print "$arr[0]";
print "$arr[1]\n";
```

This is working
**Output:**

```
Hello crypted
Hello decrypted
```

**BUT**
**main.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture capturex);

my $cmd= 'perl xyz.pl';
my @arg=("Hello");
my @arr = capture($cmd,@arg);

print "$arr[0]";
print "$arr[1]\n";
```

This is not working. It says
`"perl xyz.pl" failed to start: "The system cannot find the file specified" at main.pl line 11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only pass a single scalar, `capture` expects it to be a shell command.

As such, `capture('perl xyz.pl Hello')` works.

If you pass multiple scalars, `capture` expects the first to be a path to a program to execute. The rest are passed as arguments.

As such, `capture('perl xyz.pl', 'Hello')` doesn't work.

---

You could use

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capture );

my @cmd = ( 'perl', 'xyz.pl', 'Hello' );
capture(@cmd)
```

But you never want to use `capture` unless you pass a single scalar that's a shell command. Use `capturex` when passing a path and arguments.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my @cmd = ( 'perl', 'xyz.pl', 'Hello' );
capturex(@cmd)
```

---

But let's say you get the string `perl xyz.pl` from elsewhere. A shell needs to be invoked, so we need to convert the arguments in to shell literals.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capture );
use String::ShellQuote  qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = 'perl xyz.pl';
my @extra_args = 'Hello';
my $full_cmd = $cmd . ' ' . shell_quote(@extra_args);
capture($cmd)
```

Alternatively,

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my $cmd = 'perl xyz.pl';
my @extra_args = 'Hello';
capturex('sh', '-c', 'eval $0 "$@"', $cmd, @extra_args)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I have another question. In this, all I am doing is capturing the output of the second Perl script. Is there any way that I can return some value from the second Perl script. Say from the first script I have to call some function which is in the second script and that function returns back some value to the first. I tried require() but that would load the second script which I don't want.

Comment: @luffy008 If you don't want to load it in the current process, then running it as a separate process is the only other option. The best way to not have to run a separate process is to make it a real module that can be loaded via `use` and then the subroutine can be called directly.